# E: The package libwacom2 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it

Tags: apt, updates

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package libwacom2 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

Running Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: @Zanna i tried but didn't solve the problem

Comment: What happened? Please [edit] your question with any errors you got

Comment: @Zanna help me out with his bro ..struggling from hours...When i try to update i get :( W: http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart/dists/dist/Release.gpg: Signature by key 492EAFE8CD016A07919F1D2B9ECBEC467F0CEB10 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1) ) error ......when i try to upgrade or install software i get : (The package libwacom2 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.) this error

Comment: could you please add the full output to your question? You said the other question did not help you, so please [edit] your question to show what happens when you run `sudo dpkg --remove --force-all libwacom2` and then `sudo apt update`. If you show the full output, we can see the whole problem, hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you will need to build it. Looks simple enough, details here:

http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Libwacom